# which component is responsible for setting regionManager?

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container

which component is responsible for setting regionManager?

I am following the hands-on lab on prism on
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921141(v=pandp.40).aspx

```
public HelloWorldModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }
```

I am wondering which component is setting regionManager?

Answer (score 2):

It's a dependency injection pattern; the Unity framework ([`UnityBootstrapper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.unityextensions.unitybootstrapper%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx) to be exact) is setting the `regionManager`.  You can see the code under *Prism.UnityExtensions\UnityBootstrapper.cs* in the [Prism download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28950):

In the `ConfigureContainer` method:

```
RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IRegionManager), typeof(RegionManager), true);
```

And in the `Run` method:

```
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(this.Shell, this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>());
```

You'll notice that the `HelloWorldModule` inherits `IModule` which is the <s>Unity</s> Prism interface whose implementation the `UnityBootstrapper` injects into the class.

---

If you're not familiar with Dependency Injection, this is its classic pattern; a class requests any external dependencies (*IRegionViewRegistry* in this case) via its constructor, and the DI framework is responsible for injecting the actual implementations.

Comment: Unless I understand incorrectly, the following "You'll notice that the HelloWorldModule inherits IModule which is the Unity interface that handles allows dependencies to be injected into a class." is not entirely true. Prism as part of its module loading process uses Unity to resolve classes that implement IModule, but IModule is part of Prism, Unity does not have any particular dependency on it.

Comment: @DamianSchenkelman you're absolutely right, `IModule` is a Prism interface, which not Unity.  `UnityBootstrapper` is the class that wires up the implementation for `IModule`.